# Entity Framework Code First approach foreign key with non primary key of another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Table A:

```
public A()
{
    Bs = new List<B>();
}

public ICollection<B> Bs {get; set;}
```

Table B:

```
public B()
{
    a = new A();
}

public A a {get; set;}
```

If I have a foreign key of A's primary key int Id column to B's int column, it's working fine.

But I want a foreign key of A's unique key `varchar` column to B's `varchar` column, and when I run query it throws an error of converting varchar to int?

In short: can anyone give me idea to deal with non primary key as foreign key to other table in Entity Framework code-first approach?

Comment: how do the other properties look like? and how do you want to map a foreign key NOT to the primary key of the other table? the join would be ambiguous - there can be multiple tuples with the same value, since it's not unique - which would create a not plain relationship

Comment: In table A: consider two fields StatusId(PK) and StatusCode(Unique). In table B: I don't want to map StatusId as foreign key but I want to map Status Code as foreign key. As Roger replied support of alternate keys will be introduce in EF7.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Entity Framework does not support alternate keys. They have just started "introducing" them in version 7 - [Channel 9 video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/Alternate-Keys-in-Entity-Framework-7).